# Mapreduce why number of splits (text file) are more than 1 even for a tiny file

Tags: hadoop, split, mapreduce

I know the difference between a physical block and Inputsplits in hadoop. 
BTW I am using Hadoop 2.0 version (Yarn processing).

I have a very tiny input dataset. May be 1.5 Mb in size. When I run mapredce program that consumes this tiny dataset, during the run, it shows there are 2 input splits. Why should the tiny dataset should be split into two when it is less than 128 MB in size.

In my understanding a block size is configured to be 128 MB in size and input split is logical division of data. Meaning where does each split starts (like in which node and which block number) and where it does it end. Starting location and ending location of data is the split.

I didn't get the reason for splits in a tiny datasets.

can someone explain?
thanks
nath

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

I tried on a file of size **2.5MB** and I would get on the console from running the job

**number of splits:2

Job Counters
Launched map tasks=2**

Logically speaking, it should be one split, as I am using the default setting
split_size 128M, block_size 128M

However, I think the reason MapReduce job is splitting the input is due to this config param:

**mapreduce.job.maps: The default number of map tasks per job. Ignored when mapreduce.framework.name is "local".**

The default value is 2, as you can see in the [MapReduce defaults](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml).

You can set it if you are using **MRJob for python**

```
MRJob.JOBCONF = {'mapreduce.job.maps': '1'}
```

By doing so, I got one split, then I ran another file 450M or so with the same setting, it was split into 4 (ceil(450/128)). Which means this setting is ignored when more splits are needed.

Answer (score 0):

First try to understand how the number of splits will be decided, and it depends on two thing:

1. If you have not defined any custom split size then it will take default size which will be the block size, in your case 128 MB.
2. **This is important, now if you have *two small files*, it will be saved in *two different blocks*.** So number of splits will be two.

*Your answer is in above two point this is extra info*, now the relation between number of mapper and number of splits is one - one so number of splits will be same as number of mapper.

Comment: I have not defined number of splits in the driver class.

Comment: In that case if your file size is less than 128MB it will reside in its **individual** single block and that many number of slips will be there, check the number of blocks using `hadoop fs -fsck -block` or `hdfs dfs -fsck -block`